# django 1.8 shell_plus stuck on importing 'logging.config'

Tags: django, django-1.8

I'm trying to upgrade my django 1.7.0 project to django 1.8.

I've installed the new version, and am trying to run `manage.py shell_plus`. This appears to freeze. I've added a print statement in `python2.7/importlib/__init__.py`, and found that it's trying to import `logging.config`, and after this it appears to do nothing.

I do not know how to fix this.

Comment: Did you upgrade `django-extensions` as well? just to make sure the version of that app is compatible with Django 1.8.

Comment: I haven't. Didn't know I had to. I can upgrade this using pip too?

Comment: yes, you can can `$pip install django-extensions --upgrade` it is just one of the dependencies of you project (the one that gives you the `shell_plus` command)